# aem cq listener on multiple paths

Tags: aem, event-listener, sling

I am trying to implement an Event listener using the observation manager. I need to listen on multiple paths.

But, we can register a listener on only one path I believe. Is there a way we can listen on multiple paths?

I have tried something like this

```java
String pathvalues = "path1,path2,path3";
List < String > path = Arrays.asList(pathvalues.split(","));
session = repository.loginAdministrative(repository.getDefaultWorkspace());
observationManager = session.getWorkspace().getObservationManager();
for (String paths: path) {
 observationManager.addEventListener(this, Event.NODE_ADDED, paths, true, null, null, false);
}
```

But this is listening on only the last path it has iterated on. I guess that makes sense, so I'm still stuck.

and I found this on the net, 
[SLING-4564](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-4564)

I implemented it, but somehow its still not listening.

If anyone has any inputs, please do let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first issue:

`observationManager.addEventListener(this, Event.NODE_ADDED, paths, true, null, null, false);`

> But this is listening on only the last path it has iterated on

**This is by design**. The even listener only registers to one path and the last path provided in your loop will be the active path. Everything else before the last call to `addEventListener` will be ignored.

There are 2 possible solutions to your problem:

Register your listener on parent level and filter the events on even invocation.

OR

Use `eventFilter.setAdditionalPaths(paths);` to filter the events on multiple paths as described in [SLING-4564](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-4564)

First approach is more desirable as it allows you to implement optimal and quick filtering based on your logic. For example your quick filter could be to exclude /etc/ so you can easily evaluate the event path and check if it begins with /etc/ and discard it.

[SLING-4564](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-4564) is basically designed for large activities like OAK startup and as a general guideline for performance, your application specific event listeners should be limited to application or content specific paths rather than being global in nature.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the info. Will go with the first approach of listening on root path, but it is still a bit cumbersome, if I want to listen to a different root path.

Answer (score 2):

Check the EventConstants.EVENT_FILTER property in the following example

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingConstants;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventConstants;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler;

@Component
/**
 * The @Component annotation is the only required annotation. If this annotation is not declared for a Java class, the class is
 * not declared as a component.
 */
@Service(value = EventHandler.class)
/**
 * The @Service annotation defines whether and which service interfaces are provided by the component. This is a class annotation.
 * This annotation is used to declare <service> and <provide> elements of the component declaration.
 */
@Properties({
        @Property(name = EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC,
                value = { SlingConstants.TOPIC_RESOURCE_ADDED, SlingConstants.TOPIC_RESOURCE_CHANGED, SlingConstants.TOPIC_RESOURCE_REMOVED }),
        @Property(name = EventConstants.EVENT_FILTER, value = "(|(path=/content/dam/*/jcr:content)(assetPath=/content/dam/*))") })
public class ExampleServiceImpl implements EventHandler {

    final String[] eventProps = { "resourceAddedAttributes", "resourceChangedAttributes", "resourceRemovedAttributes" };

    public void handleEvent(org.osgi.service.event.Event event) {
        for (String eventProp : eventProps) {
            String[] props = (String[]) event.getProperty(eventProp);

        }
    }
}
```